# Which synagogues in the Catskill, NY area are active during Shabbat and High Holidays?

Tags: synagogue, travel, chutz-laaretz

I am looking to spend a Shabbat in one of the historic Catskill mountain, NY area synagogues (i.e. any shul located in Sullivan, Orange, Ulster, Greene and Delaware counties.) during the summer as well as possibly Rosh Hashanna.

The only 3 synagogues that I was able to locate any info about having active services are the large old shul / yeshiva in Woodridge, NY, the one in Livingston Manor and the one in Mountaindale, NY. I know that one of the oldest is in Spring Glen, another one in Glen Wild and a third in Parksville. But, I couldn't locate any info on when they conduct services, if at all.

Does anyone have any advice regarding how I can find out? Is there, perhaps, a central contact person, number that would know about **all** the different shuls scattered through the Catskills. There are a number of them that I saw driving by on a weekday about 2 years ago, but they were closed, and there was no info on the web or otherwise that I could find.

Comment: You may wish to look beyond synagogues in the literal sense. There's a _y'shiva g'dola_ in South Fallsburg. It will likely have services.

Comment: Landfield Avenue Synagogue - Chabad

Comment: The Loch Sheldrake Hebrew Congregation may hold High Holy Day services. I was a member through 2012. At that point, the synagogue was moving from Modern Orthodox slightly to the right.

Comment: Is this on topic?

Answer (score 1):

Google gives [Synagogues](http://www.yellowpages.com/monticello-ny/synagogues) which has a number of listings

I should warn you that the list appears to contain Reform temples, churches pretending to be synagogues and other organizations (such as a Mikveh or JCC). You would need to check further for actual details.
I do not know which ones are actually synagogues. You can also check with Chabad as they should have a list.

I do know that the Monticello synagogue has been in existance since my great-grandfather was the rabbi in the 1920's.

[Landfield Avenue Synagogue - Chabad](http://www.chabad.org/centers/default_cdo/aid/118179/jewish/Landfield-Avenue-Synagogue-Chabad.htm)

18 Landfield Avenue
Monticello, NY 12701 USA
Mailing Address:
P.O. Box 410
Monticello, NY 12701 USA
Phone: 845-794-8470

Comment: The rabbi and rebbetzin of the Land field Avenue Synagogue were extremely helpful and hospitable to my family when we had to bury mother, A"H, in the area.

Comment: Thanks. This is somewhat useful, but also a bit "murky". Someone less educated than me could rather easily mistake one of these "synagogues" for may be disguised as a church. Messianic group, J for J, etc.

Comment: @DanF Good point. I will add a caveat to the pointer. I see some chuches pretending that can be identified from the name.